# I am working on a Arduino Uno. Errors: "'RX' not declared in the scope." and "duplicate case value" for switch case

Tags: c++, bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno

Uno controls 6 servo motors on getting command via RX pin. This is the initial part of my code. What does these errors mean? How to resolve the errors?

```
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
  #include <Servo.h>

  Servo servo_1;    
  Servo servo_2;    
  Servo servo_3;    
  Servo servo_4;    
  Servo servo_5;    
  Servo servo_6;    
  SoftwareSerial bluetooth(RX_PIN,TX_PIN);     

  int RX_PIN= 0;    
  int TX_PIN= 1;    
  int motornumber;     
  int pos=0;    

  void setup() {    
  // put your setup code here, to run once:    
  Serial.begin(9600);     
  bluetooth.begin(4800);     

  servo_1.attach(3);    
  servo_2.attach(5);     
  servo_3.attach(6);     
  servo_4.attach(9);      
  servo_5.attach(10);     
  servo_6.attach(11);     

  }      

  void loop()     
  {     
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:    
  if(bluetooth.available())     
  {     
      motornumber =Serial.write(bluetooth.read());     
      switch(motornumber)     
    {     
        case '7':{                                                //7 for servo_1,1 for servo_2,2 for servo_3,3 for servo_4,4 for servo_5,5 for servo_6.
             for(pos=0; pos<=180; pos++)     
        { 
           servo_1.write(pos);      
           delay(800);    
        }    
             for(pos=180; pos>=0; pos--)
          {
            servo_1.write(pos);    
            bluetooth.print(9);      
          }      
          break;     
        }       
  }      
   }     
}
```

P.S: For reading the data via RX, is `bluetooth.read()` appropriate or `Serial.write(bluetooth.read())`??

Comment: `Serial.write` returns the number of bytes it wrote. I doubt that is the value you're interested in (especially since you're looking for `'7'`, i.e. 55). And you probably need to declare `RX_PIN` and `TX_PIN` before using them.

Comment: Get your code formatting corrected and it will explain everything.

Comment: Why are you using a `switch` for only one case?

Comment: I am using switch for 50 cases. For convenience, I have uploaded only 1 case. That will represent all my cases.
@molbdnilo -for obtaining integer values which the serial port receives, should i directly use "bluetooth.read()" ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error "RX not declared in this scope", you should declare your variables

```
int RX_PIN= 0;    
int TX_PIN= 1;
```

before using them here

```
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(RX_PIN,TX_PIN);
```

result:

```
/*some lines here*/

Servo servo_1;    
Servo servo_2;    
Servo servo_3;    
Servo servo_4;    
Servo servo_5;    
Servo servo_6;    

int RX_PIN= 0;   
int TX_PIN= 1;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(RX_PIN,TX_PIN);

int motornumber;     
int pos=0;

/*code continues here*/
```

For the "duplicate case value" error, you should indent your code correctly, and you might be able to see duplicate cases.